# pyspark:why stop() function doesn't work correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

First, I created a sparksession,The stop function is then called，At this point, should not be able to use sparkseesion after running the stop function, but the stop() function is not in effect, the sparksesion instance can still be used。

```
conf = (SparkConf()
            #.setMaster("local")
             .setMaster("spark://master:7077")
            .setAppName("My_APP")
            .set("spark.executor.cores", '1')
            .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
            )
sess = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
sess.stop()
DataFrame = sess.sql("show tables")
print(DataFrame)
```

What can I do to close sparksession? thanks.

Comment: This is the program output：

DataFrame[database: string, tableName: string, isTemporary: boolean]
<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x7fe3b8e709b0>